# Python virtual environment, can't find '__main__' module in

Tags: python, flask

I am studying Flask,with my first book example I have encountered problem

```
>>> from flask import Flask
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> @app.route('/')
... def index():
...     return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'
... 
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     app.run(debug=True)
... 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/home/tati/flasky/venv/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
(venv) tati@tati-System-Product-Name:~/flasky$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

My Python venv is 2.7.Does this creates havoc or not?
If I go out,from command line(conda python installation)

```
python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you save this code to a file and run the file, rather than running it in the interpreter?

Comment: @viraptor I can run script from the venve now,I have saved the file into flasky directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that with `debug=True` flask [will relaunch the python script](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/368ccb07d097660156eb19a0ec2042bc53e68238/werkzeug/_reloader.py#L105-L126) to run an additional thread with the reloader. When running from the console [it can't find any script](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/368ccb07d097660156eb19a0ec2042bc53e68238/werkzeug/_reloader.py#L53-L65) because there isn't any. 
You can work around this removing `debug=True`.

Also, in the console you just call whatever needs to be called, no need for `if __name__ == '__main__'` idiom; there is no alternative code path.

Anyway, the console is not the best option to learn Flask. Soon enough you'll need somewhere to put the templates and additional files like blueprints, etc.

The best option in my opinion is to **create a package for your study app**. Just create a directory with a `__init__.py` file and an additional one `app.py` where you put the tutorial code. Remember to adjust your PYTHONPATH accordingly.

Comment: is it a bug of flask? is it reported?